# Terminate a running Windows application using a Perl script

Tags: windows, perl, process

I'm trying to close a running Windows application from the same Perl program that started it. I'm trying to use the `taskkill` command but it isn't working.

This is my Perl code

```
 system("D:/file.rtf");
 sleep(2);
```

After the `sleep` I want to terminate the process that opened the file. I have tried

```
 taskkill("D:/file.rtf");
```

but it isn't working. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If `$f` is an open filehandle, you close it with `close $f`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @WilliamPursell `system(filename)` command is open the file. Then which is automatically close by the command. I'm not say about file handle it is just about the windows command to use into the perlscript.  Else how to close the window using perl.? can you understand edit my question.

Comment: `system(filename)` does not open a file.  It spawns a shell which attempts to execute the file.

Comment: @Hussain: I have rewritten your question. Does it say what you meant?

Comment: @Borodin Thank you. any option for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script will probably need to know which application (executable name) will open the given file (`file.rtf`). The process name won't be the name of the data file. For robustness, I would choose an application in which to open the file (Wordpad or Word, probably) and explicitly invoke it. That way, you know what process to kill.

If you're creating your own processes, then [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Process-0.16/Process.pm) should allow you to do what you want.

Here's a code snippet that opens a text file in notepad. I don't adequately understand why you must give the full path to the executable and also provide it in the arguments parameter, but that's the way it is. Much of this code was taken directly from the Win32::Process documentation.

```
#!perl

use Win32::Process;
use Win32;

sub ErrorReport{
    print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
}

Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,
                       "C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe",
                       "notepad test.txt",
                       0,
                       NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       ".")|| die ErrorReport();


sleep(3);

$ProcessObj->Kill(0);
```

In your case, I'd probably use Wordpad (`write.exe`).

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your full code or knowing what the command your calling does its hard to say. Generally making a call to system will wait until that process provides a return. So if we use a simple example like notepad. that process wont return until notepad is finished. which in your case means it wouldnt go to the next lines of your perl code to close it until after it was closed. I have draughted the below working example to hopefully give you an idea of how this can be worked. It uses fork to spawn a sub process to launch the notepad application, then the parent process waits 5 seconds before closing it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pid = fork;
unless($pid){
system('C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe');
} else {
    sleep 5;
    system('TASKKILL /F /IM notepad* /T 2>nul');
}
```

This will produce the output

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID 1240 (child process of PID 4828) has been terminated.
```

You should then see the notepad window has been closed. However this is a generic example to show you how it works. In this case the input args to taskkill would kill all notepad processes even ones not spawned by out perl code.

Its worth while haveing a read on the task kill documentation or windows here [taskkill documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602.aspx)